# Javafx build error using Ant

Tags: java, javafx, ant

In my ant file I have given description to generate exe file but doesnot generate it instead it generates an executable jar file. When I run this jar file it shows error as this **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.util.proxy.MethodFilter**. Here is my ant build file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="HMS" default="do-deploy" basedir="."  xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
<target name="init-fx-tasks">
    <path id="fxant">
        <filelist>
            <file name="${java.home}\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar"/>
            <file name="${java.home}\lib\jfxrt.jar"/>
        </filelist>
    </path>

    <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"
        uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
        classpathref="fxant"/>
</target>
<target name="setup-staging-area">
    <delete dir="externalLibs" />
    <delete dir="project" />
    <delete dir="projectRefs" />

    <mkdir dir="externalLibs" />

    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="jasperreports-fonts-6.5.1.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="commons-collections-3.2.1-1.0.0.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="antlr-complete-3.5.2.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="jfreechart.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="jasperreports-6.5.1.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\fx\report\jars">
            <filename name="joda-time-2.9.9.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="jta-1.1.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="javax.persistence-2.1.1.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="jasperreports-javaflow.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\fx\report\jars">
            <filename name="jasperreports-functions-6.5.1.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="fontawesomefx-8.4.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="aopalliance-1.0.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="controlsfx-8.40.12.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="spring-expression-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="poi-3.17.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="commons-lang-2.4.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="org.eclipse.fx.ide.css.jfx8_3.0.0.201705220750.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="commons-dbcp-1.4.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="commons-digester-2.1.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="javassist-3.18.1-GA .jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="itextpdf-5.5.13.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="itext-4.2.1.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS With Splash_lib">
            <filename name="logback-classic-1.0.13.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <mkdir dir="project" />
    <copy todir="project">
        <fileset dir="E:\azhar\complete\complete 23062018\HMS">
            <include name="src/**" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <mkdir dir="projectRefs" />
</target>
<target name='do-compile'>
    <delete dir="build" />
    <mkdir dir="build/src" />
    <mkdir dir="build/libs" />
    <mkdir dir="build/classes" />

    <!-- Copy project-libs references -->
    <copy todir="build/libs">
        <fileset dir="externalLibs">
            <include name="org.eclipse.fx.ide.css.jfx8_3.0.0.201705220750.jar"/>
            <include name="jasperreports-functions-6.5.1.jar"/>
            <include name="antlr-complete-3.5.2.jar"/>
            <include name="spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
            <include name="slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar"/>
            <include name="commons-digester-2.1.jar"/>
            <include name="spring-expression-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
            <include name="jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar"/>
            <include name="hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar"/>
            <include name="javassist-3.18.1-GA .jar"/>
            <include name="commons-lang-2.4.jar"/>
            <include name="jasperreports-javaflow.jar"/>
            <include name="fontawesomefx-8.4.jar"/>
            <include name="spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
            <include name="hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar"/>
            <include name="dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
            <include name="commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
            <include name="spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
            <include name="hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar"/>
            <include name="commons-collections-3.2.1-1.0.0.jar"/>
            <include name="spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
            <include name="spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
            <include name="spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
            <include name="jasperreports-6.5.1.jar"/>
            <include name="itext-4.2.1.jar"/>
            <include name="controlsfx-8.40.12.jar"/>
            <include name="aopalliance-1.0.jar"/>
            <include name="logback-classic-1.0.13.jar"/>
            <include name="itextpdf-5.5.13.jar"/>
            <include name="hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar"/>
            <include name="poi-3.17.jar"/>
            <include name="mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar"/>
            <include name="joda-time-2.9.9.jar"/>
            <include name="jasperreports-fonts-6.5.1.jar"/>
            <include name="javax.persistence-2.1.1.jar"/>
            <include name="commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar"/>
            <include name="jfreechart.jar"/>
            <include name="spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
            <include name="jta-1.1.jar"/>
            <include name="commons-dbcp-1.4.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <!-- Copy project references -->

    <!-- Copy project sources itself -->
    <copy todir="build/src">
        <fileset dir="project/src">
            <include name="**/*"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <javac includeantruntime="false" source="1.8" target="1.8" srcdir="build/src" destdir="build/classes" encoding="Cp1252">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="build/libs">
                <include name="*"/>
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </javac>

    <!-- Copy over none Java-Files -->
    <copy todir="build/classes">
    <fileset dir="project/src">
        <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
    </fileset>
    </copy>


</target>
<target name="do-deploy" depends="setup-staging-area, do-compile, init-fx-tasks">
    <delete file="dist"/>
    <delete file="deploy" />

    <mkdir dir="dist" />
    <mkdir dir="dist/libs" />

    <copy todir="dist/libs">
        <fileset dir="externalLibs">
            <include name="*" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>


    <fx:resources id="appRes">
        <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="HMS.jar"/>
        <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="libs/*"/>
    </fx:resources>

    <fx:application id="fxApplication"
        name="HMS"
        mainClass="com.arrss.hms.application.Main"
        toolkit="fx"
    />

    <mkdir dir="build/classes/META-INF" />



    <fx:jar destfile="dist/HMS.jar">
        <fx:application refid="fxApplication"/>
        <fileset dir="build/classes">
        </fileset>
        <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>

        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="Pentaxis"/>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="HMS"/>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value=""/>
            <attribute name="JavaFX-Feature-Proxy" value="None"/>
        </manifest>
    </fx:jar>


    <mkdir dir="deploy" />
    <!-- Need to use ${basedir} because somehow the ant task is calculating the directory differently -->
    <fx:deploy
        embedJNLP="false"
        extension="false"
        includeDT="false"
        offlineAllowed="true"
        outdir="${basedir}/deploy"
        outfile="HMS" nativeBundles="exe"
        updatemode="background" >

        <fx:platform basedir="${java.home}"/>
        <fx:info title="HMS" vendor="Pentaxis"/>

        <fx:application refId="fxApplication"/>
        <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>
    </fx:deploy>

    <fx:csstobin outdir="build/classes">
        <fileset dir="build/classes" includes="**/*.css"/>
    </fx:csstobin>

</target>
```

On my my view the error is shown because JVM does not identify the jars of the project. This is the same error I get when I export the project from eclipse directly as executable jar and jars as sub-folders. But, error does not appear when I export the project as executable jar and package the required jars in it, and it works fine. 
But what I want is, to have the jars outside the executable jar. Please help.

Comment: a) If you run an executable .jar ... b) that has "javaassist" as a dependency ... then c) YOU MUST SPECIFY YOUR "javaassist.jar" IN YOUR CLASSPATH.  Q: what is your classpath when you execute the .jar?  ALSO: in your ant build.xml: `<include name="javassist-3.18.1-GA .jar"/>`.  Q: Is the space before ` .jar` a typo?  Does everything "work" if you change it to `javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar` (no extra space)?

Comment: No it does not solve the problem

Comment: Thanks. There was a space in the name  of jar, I removed it and it worked. It was you who made me notice that. Thanks again